# Slow Network Transfer Through Linux Firewall VM

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, vmware-esx, slow-connection

We have a RedHat 5.8 VM running on ESX on top of Cisco UCS that is acting as a firewall using iptables.  The box has multiple nics, one nic serves as the gateway to our network with the other nics each going to a separate VLAN/network.  The problem I'm seeing is that doing an iperf test from a host directly to the Firewall VM gives 800+ Mbps speed but trying to do an iperf test from a host outside the firewall to a host inside the firewall (causing the traffic to pass through the firewall) yields speeds of about 30Mbps or less.

The details:

- I'm not sure what release or versions of ESX or UCS we are running, but I can find out if that's important.  Our sysadmin keeps it up to date so they're most likely within the last couple of updates.
- I know we are using the VMXNET 3 driver for the network adapters.
- All connections are verified to be 1Gbps.

What I've tried:

- From what I had read, the e1000 driver has better results, so we added a couple of nics using that driver and iperf tested through those interfaces with the same results.
- Checked that LRO was disabled on the tested interfaces.  When I ran 'ethtool -K ethX lro off', it reports 'no offload settings changed' which I assume to mean it's already disabled.
- Also disabled TSO on the tested interfaces.
- When I did my speed tests, I was typically testing from a physical device to a virtual device through the firewall on the same cluster.  I also tried testing from a virtual device to a virtual device through the firewall and got the same results.
- Disabled iptables and ran speed tests, receiving the same results.
- None of the items above changed anything except possibly making things even slower (I got <10 Mbps at one point).

Because I can get 800+ Mbps going to the firewall itself, that leads me to think that there is nothing wrong with the configuration of the nics themselves.  I feel like it's some issue with the forwarding on the OS itself since it only seems to manifest when it's passing traffic through the firewall.  I should also note that I didn't observe any CPU spikes during this process.

I'm sure I'm leaving out some details, so if there are any further questions, let me know.  I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution.  We had to disable LRO at the blade level on the UCS (as shown here -> http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Disable_LRO). Once we did that, the speeds bumped up to 700+MBps, limited only because of the CPU and iptables processing.